# Error in rvest::html_table(nodes)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I am tryin to use the "smapr" package on R to download and process the SMAP data following the set of examples from [this](https://rpubs.com/ials2un/smap1) website,  but at the first step only getting this error

> Error in rvest::html_table(nodes)[[1](https://rpubs.com/ials2un/smap1)] : subscript out of bounds.

Despite installing all the necessary packages and details.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Afterwards, review your question to make it clearer for others.

Comment: You can also read some [R-specific ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of how to create an MCVE